# Windows Installer not deleting files on uninstall

Tags: wix, uninstallation, windows-installer

I have been using WiX to create an installer for my project. It's fairly simple, just drop some files in a number of spots and run a VBScript to generate one last file.

After some difficulties with the VBS I got it installing, but when I uninstall the package disappears out of Control Panel but the files that were installed are still there.

I have install and uninstall logs, and also have posted the WiX source file. Links are below.

Any help is much appreciated!

[install log](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0qy0SfToYUzMUJYMk00UjhreDg/edit?usp=sharing)

[WiX source](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0qy0SfToYUzR0FDMXc2cXhvMDQ/edit?usp=sharing)

[uninstall log](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0qy0SfToYUzUUtXVUxpQ0lESm8/edit?usp=sharing)

Note that this is being installed on Server 2003.

I know it's full of drive letters and full paths, and that isn't best practice, but that's where the files need to go. This doesn't go to a variety of computer types and configurations; there are over ten thousand of these systems in our retail locations and they're all identical.

Comment: I think you mixed up the links for your log files, but is the problem just that the files created by your vb script are not deleted, or also the wix Components? You seem to be running the script custom action on both install and uninstall.

Comment: I may well have messed up the links, sorry about that. The problem is that all installed files were not being removed. I didn't expect it to get the one that I create out of VBS.

I saw that the script was running on install and uninstall but figured I'd work on that next. It's a small file that gets created and I'm not sure I actually want to delete it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I was running the Custom Action at the wrong time, so it ran too late in the uninstall to define where the C Drive is.

I changed from what is in the WiX above to:

```
<CustomAction Id="CA_SetCDrive" Directory="C_DRIVE" Value="c:\" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
     <Custom Action="CA_SetCDrive" After="CostFinalize" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>

<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
     <Directory Id="C_DRIVE" Name="CDrive" />
</Directory>
```

and now it works fine.

Comment: How do you know the "C drive" is "c:"? You might be better off using one of Windows Installer's pre-defined [System Folder Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#system_folder_properties). Every version of every operating system has its own directory layout scheme of system and user directories. Windows Installer attempts to make it easy to go along with it.

Comment: Is the other problem of not deleting the WiX created files also gone? Besides, Tom is right: setting directory properties to hardcoded values like this is more than bad style, it is wrong setup design. You don't need a custom action for this, just use the predefined directory "WindowsVolume" (goes to the root of the drive containing the OS) and make a directory "MYFOLDER" OR "INSTALLDIR" or whatsoever underneath. Really better because Win guidline conform is using a default path under "ProgramFilesFolder" or "ProgramFiles64Folder", instead of "WindowsVolume".

Comment: (Info: Using an own directory name with CAPS letters gives the builtin option of overriding that directory from the commandline, when needed sometimes).

Comment: I know this is 7 years later, but @TomBlodget, it's not a normal environment. The MSI is installed only to a specific single device in our retail environment. There are over 10,000 of these devices in the US and they're all running identical software including OS image and drive layout.